# Search engine for geotagged images, (drone) videos, etc

Tags: photography, maps, search, gps, search-engine

This would just be a search engine that indexes EXIF tags, etc., lets you view a map, and any geotagged images or videos would be shown as points on the map.

Answer (score 0):

The only one I know of is https://www.flickr.com/map/, but it only shows images from Flicker itself, and seems to have become buggy over the years.